# CSS Drop Down Menu, Nested Lists - Child List Items Overlap Parent List Items

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a CSS drop down menu but the problem is that child list items overlap parent list items as you can see in the [picture](http://i48.tinypic.com/jku1qa.png).

I found the source of the problem to be the **padding: 10px 5px;** in line 12 - When removed, the problem is solved. But I need the padding for the look. I read [Inline elements and padding](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline) which addresses a similar issue but even the solution provided in the article - using **float: left;** instead of **display: inline;** - does not solve my problem.

Why does this happen and what is the solution?

HTML Code

```
<ul id="navigation_2">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
     <ul>
        <li>Who We Are</li>
        <li>Our Goal</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS Code

```
ul#navigation_2 
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
font-family: "Century Gothic","HelveticaNeueLT Pro 45 Lt",sans-serif;
}
ul#navigation_2 li
{
float: left;
position: relative;
padding: 10px 5px;
font-size: 114%;
text-align: center;
width: 100px;
}
ul#navigation_2 li a
{
text-decoration: none;
}
ul#navigation_2 li a:link, a:visited, a:active
{
color: black;
}
ul#navigation_2 li:hover
{
background-color: red;
}
ul#navigation_2 li ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
display: none;
}
ul#navigation_2 li ul li
{
display: block;
width: 150px;
text-align: left;
}
ul#navigation_2 li:hover ul
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
background-color: #CBD966;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, I have a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hzCZY/2/

Never underestimate the power of `inline-block`!  Basically your list was colliding with the text 'About' as opposed to the red box around the text 'About'.  I formatted the actual `a` tag to be the red block instead, an `inline-block`, which then collided correctly with the `ul` below it.

If you need any more explanation I'd be more than happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could meanwhile find another solution as well. Just by adding `margin: 10px -5px;` under `ul#navigation_2 li ul` is the problem solved. As simple as that! What do you think of that?

Comment: I'd say that's covering it up with duct tape instead of pulling out a hammer and nails, but hey it gets the job done.